# MVC2 Handling Exceptions from RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

My controller is decorated with `[HandleError]` and `[HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(CustomException), View="CustomView")]`.  I have views that consist of multiple partial views from multiple controllers, so we're displaying our partial views using `<% RenderAction(...) %>` but now we have a case where our action being rendered is throwing a CustomException.  I overrode `OnException` inside `HandleErrorAttribute` which gets called (twice for some reason) with the `CustomException`, and then two more times with `System.Web.HttpUnhandledException`, before being redirected to the default `Error.aspx` page instead of to `CustomView` where it should go with this error.

Also, if I remove `[HandleError]` but keep `[HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(CustomException), View="CustomView")]` the `HandleErrorAttribute.OnException` override never fires.

How do I throw CustomException types from an action that renders a partial view, and still have the app redirect to my CustomView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the exception is so deep, but I got it to work adding this code into `OnException` inside `HandleErrorAttribute`

```
if (filterContext.Exception.InnerException != null &&
            filterContext.Exception.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
            filterContext.Exception.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
            filterContext.Exception.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(CustomException))
        {
            filterContext.Exception = filterContext.Exception.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException;
            View = "CustomView";
        }
```